# React Native Image Component showing white blank

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

Hi I am new to react native and have been playing around some components on the doc.

I wrote some code for an Image component, but it shows white blank even though I can check the path to the image stored in Firestore. Uploading and storing an image is successfully done, and I can see the path in the Firebase console (also, I can see the path on the screen).
[image]

### Here is the code Image component placed in.

```js
import {
  Image,
  ImageBackground,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from "react-native";
import { useAuthContext } from "../../contexts/AuthContext";
import { NotYetVerified } from "./NotYetVerified";
import { SignoutBtn } from "./SignoutBtn";
import { useFirestoreContext } from "../../contexts/FirestoreContext";
import { ImagePickerBtn } from "./ImagePickerBtn";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export const UserProfile = () => {
  const { currUser } = useAuthContext();
  const { getUserInfo, userInfo } = useFirestoreContext();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    getUserInfo(currUser.email);
  }, []);

  console.log("UserProfile.js userInfo: ", userInfo.photoUrl, currUser.photoURL);
  return (
    <>
      {/* remove the ! mark when publishing */}
      {currUser.emailVerified ? (
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: "center",
          }}
        >
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => getUserInfo(currUser.email)}>
            <Text>Get user info</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Text>{userInfo?.email}</Text>
          <Text>{userInfo?.photoUrl}</Text>
          <ImagePickerBtn />
          <Image
            style={styles.photo}
            source={{
              uri: userInfo.photoUrl,
            }}
            resizeMethod="resize"
            resizeMode="contain"
          />
        </View>
      ) : (
        <NotYetVerified />
      )}
      <SignoutBtn />
    </>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  photo: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    borderRadius: 50,
    borderColor: "black",
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
});
```

### I don't think it's necessary, but just in case, code below is for uploading a file.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Button, Image, View, Platform } from "react-native";
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";
import {getDownloadURL, getStorage, ref, uploadBytes} from 'firebase/storage'
import { useAuthContext } from "../../contexts/AuthContext";
import { doc, setDoc, updateDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../../firebase.config";
import { updateProfile } from "firebase/auth";
export const ImagePickerBtn = () => {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);

  const {currUser} = useAuthContext()
  const pickImage = async () => {
    // No permissions request is necessary for launching the image library
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });

    console.log(result);

    if (!result.canceled) {
      const storage = getStorage(); // the storage itself 
      const fileRef = ref(storage, currUser.uid + '.png'); // how the image will be addressed inside the storage

      // convert image to array of bytes.
      const img = await fetch(result.uri);
      const blob = await img.blob();

      await uploadBytes(fileRef, result.uri); // upload the image 
      const url = await getDownloadURL(fileRef); // get the url of the image
      console.log(url); // print the url of the image 
      await updateDoc(doc(db, "users", currUser.uid), {photoUrl: url}); // set the url of the image in the database
      await updateProfile(currUser, {photoURL: url}); // set the url of the image in the database})
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <Button title="Pick an image from camera roll" onPress={pickImage} />
      {image && (
        <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Oh, btw, I am not using ```@react-native-firebase/storage```, but normal firebase v9.

Comment: Try doing `source={{uri: userInfo?.photoUrl || "https://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/lego/images/a/ac/No-Image-Basic.png/revision/latest?cb=20130819001030", }}`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I tried that option already and didn't work well

Comment: Sorry about that. Listen for errors with [image loading](https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/image#onerror). What does it say?